# How do I clear up textures on my desktop?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, themes, screen, brightness

I have an nvidia Geforce GT 430 installed, I do have the "proprietary driver" x servers setting thing, but yet everything looks kind of rough, like rough edges and with a LOT of contrast, similar to what would look on windows if the nvidia graphic card wasn't installed.

How can I have that smooth ubuntu bright/contrast correction and smooth edges, instead of rough edges (i.e. the "refresh" button on firefox looks more like an octagon rather than a circle)

Comment: using the same monitor/display resolution you're used to?

Comment: i used 1366x768 on windows, but i can't seem to put that on ubuntu, i have 1280x720 both in the display setting on ubuntu and on the x server settings from the nvidia thing.

Comment: That could be why it looks different... not sure how to change it though, especially if it doesn't show up in `xrandr`

Comment: @favourites I almost forgot about the themes. A really easy way to search themes using the synaptic package manager `sudo apt-get install synaptic` It's alot like software center but more stripped down with long lists of results for your searches. Be carefull to pay attention when you install packages because sometimes installing the wrong app will want to uninstall something you want to keep so just read the changes before you agree to them and don't just press enter. Search themes or gtk3 themes. To change themes, install unity-tweak-tool or gnome-tweak-tool (or both).

Comment: @favourites also, more themes can be found here http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install compizconfig-settings-manager. Open ccsm, and click on the OpenGL tab to change the settings.

First, make sure this plugin is enabled. Next, on the "texture filter" setting, change the setting to "Best"

[image]

Also, go to "General Options" and to the "Display Settings" tab. Make sure "Detect Outputs" is enabled. Then, I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try clicking "Edit" and manually setting the resolution to 1366x768+0+0.

Next, make sure you have enabled the "Composite" plugin and do not enable "Copy to Texture".

Finally, scroll down to "Effects" and disable "animations" and any other effect as well (make sure all the effects are disabled).

Comment: that worked like a charm, thank you so much for your answer and the time you put into it! :)

edit: i skiped the manually setting the resolution to 1366x768+0+0, if you're not sure, i'm not safe

Comment: cool. if this works, please click the icon on the left to accept it as the answer, thanks!